# Scrollable tabs on non-holo Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to implement "dropdown navigation" or "scrollable tabs + swipe" to non-holo Android versions? I'm thinking about making two separate apps, one for Android 1.6 - 2.3 and second for Android 4.0+, but updating will be problematic.

Comment: [ActionBarSherlock?](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Woah, looks amazing. I have never seen it before :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library for "Drop-down navigation" and [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) for scrollable tabs